# Error when working with qs, does not take a field in the query

Tags: django, django-models

I have a queryset with data. I want to add an annotate for it with data from another qs. To do this, I filter by pk and by FK field, I take in_stock values in this field, but I get error: `Related Field got invalid lookup: in_stock`. This way the query will work if you pass product, without its fields, but I specifically need to refer to __. How can I add a query to make it work?

```
qs.annotate(test=Subquery(OrderList.objects.filter(order=OuterRef('pk'), product__in_stock=True).values('pk'))
```

Comment: Share your models...

Comment: OrderList has an FK field on the product table, there is a field with the value in_stock. I need to refer to the FK field in my query